# Updating SQL Tables in R

Tags: sql, r

Any suggestions on updating selected rows (based on a unique id) in a SQL table from R?
I can query and write tables with dbquery and dbwritetable, but have yet to find a function or syntax correct sql statement or oob function to perform an update. My requirements are simple, I have a dataframe (df) with updates I'd like to send to a data table (sql table) based on unique id's.

Answer (score 1):

You can send an `UPDATE` statement with `dbSendQuery` :

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE mtcars SET cyl = 7 WHERE cyl = 6")

<SQLiteResult>
  SQL  UPDATE mtcars SET cyl=7 WHERE cyl = 6
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 7
```

Comment: awesome, you saved me hours trying to find this. Thx

Comment: OK perfect! Would you then mind accepting the answer, it could help others

Answer (score 0):

I took this a step further and used a combination of delete and append as another way of updating:

```
x <- c(id) # a vector of row id's to delete
xString <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", x)) 
sql_fmt <- "delete from TABLE NAME where id in (%s)"
sql <- sprintf(sql_fmt, xString)
dbSendQuery(con, sql)
dbWriteTable(conn = con,"TABLE NAME",data frame,append = T)
```